# X-Y scatterplot

Tags: plotting

Hi I have a simple question. How do I plot the following with Day 1 as my X axis and Day 2 as my Y axis? I need the 22 variances plotted according to the Day they were taken from (these were originally 3D measurements taken over 2 days with the same specimens each day, there were 11 specimens and 22 xyz measurements from which I have taken the variances).

Can someone kindly help me out? I can't even find Scatterplot listed in Mathematica docs, do they call it something else?

```
{{{"ID", "Day", 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12., 
13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22.}, {"H. sapiens", 
1., 145.7, 153.2, 164.6, 161.1, 170.8, 191.7, 179.2, 178.5, 198.5, 
169.9, 135.8, 182.8, 205.3, 210.3, 197.3, 238.4, 207.4, 209., 
188.6, 201.3, 210.2, 206.9}, {"H. sapiens", 2., 146.8, 152.7, 
165.6, 165.1, 172.4, 189.2, 179.2, 193.9, 199.7, 172.9, 136.1, 
181.8, 204.3, 212.3, 197.4, 238., 205.7, 211.5, 191.5, 204.3, 
218.2, 204.2}, {"Pan troglodytes", 
1., -200.9, -230.2, -205.5, -238.8, -237.3, -207.1, -213.2, \
-221.6, -225.9, -247.1, -242.6, -266.5, -259.1, -258., -266.1, -259., \
-227.3, -228.9, -212.1, -213.6, -223.9, -225.1}, {"Pan troglodytes", 
2., -199.4, -229.6, -203.5, -243.6, -238.6, -205.7, -213.1, \
-222.3, -227.3, -258.1, -242.9, -265.4, -265.1, -258., -269.9, -260., \
-228.2, -233.3, -212.3, -215.1, -225.4, -223.6}, {"Pan verus ", 1., 
261.2, 273., 274., 283., 285.06, 300., 294., 305.037, 315.33, 
289.08, 263.6, 298.46, 306.3, 316.7, 306.5, 331.6, 320.81, 323.7, 
298.13, 312.79, 319.2, 310.2}, {"Pan verus", 2., 264.1, 268.7, 
273.1, 289.19, 288.03, 299.9, 291.9, 304.137, 316.54, 289.675, 
263.4, 298.58, 309.3, 316.2, 306., 332.3, 323.31, 327.4, 297.26, 
310.95, 321.8, 310.9}, {"Pan schweinfurthii ", 1., 230.6, 241.2, 
241., 257.3, 253.3, 274.1, 265.9, 272.36, 280.147, 259.21, 229.8, 
268.19, 277.62, 286.6, 275.56, 306.3, 287.4, 292.04, 270.36, 
283.35, 291.3, 281.13}, {"Pan schweinfurthii ", 2., 226.9, 237.9, 
239.9, 254.6, 257., 273.7, 262., 273.33, 282.84, 260.05, 229.6, 
267.49, 278.23, 287.9, 272.72, 306.2, 287.58, 287.92, 270.85, 
283.37, 292.3, 281.88}, {"Pan paniscus ", 
1., -421.9, -447., -420.9, -454.5, -451.7, -419.8, -427.8, -431.9, \
-445.7, -463.4, -459.2, -476.3, -470.1, -466.5, -475.5, -450.1, \
-439.5, -445.8, -417.4, -419.5, -434.4, -432.2}, {"Pan paniscus", 
2., -426.2, -447.9, -421.5, -455.6, -453., -420.4, -428.7, -432.7, \
-441.5, -466.8, -459.5, -476.4, -470.9, -467.2, -474.7, -472.5, \
 -437.5, -446.9, -416.4, -424.7, -433.1, -437.}, {"G. gorilla ", 
1., -175.9, -204., -175.1, -221., -217., -168., -187., -198., \
-213., -229., -220.8, -251.8, -251., -245., -256., -243., -211., \
-224., -190., -194., -210., -212.}, {"G. gorilla ", 2., -180.8, -205.,
214.1, -228., -223., -167., -191., -195., -206., -242.9, -221.6, \
-251.8, -253., -243., -256., -243., -211., -224., -189.8, -196., \
-210., -215.}, {"G. graueri ", 1., 220., 192., 222., 177., 184., 228.,
214., 205., 187., 162., 174., 147., 155., 162., 145., 170., 194., 
186., 221.2, 215.5, 198.8, 198.3}, {"G. graueri ", 2., 221., 189., 
226., 182., 179., 230., 214., 210., 188., 161., 172., 146., 153., 
156., 146., 169., 193., 189., 221.2, 220.6, 202.2, 
196.9}, {"G. beringei", 
1., -763., -793.5, -762.2, -810.3, -802., -749.7, -771., -777., \
-783., -828., -809.3, -836.9, -833., -828., -837.9, -809., -788., \
-795., -767.3, -768.4, -789., -782.8}, {"G. beringei", 
2., -763.3, -791.9, -761.3, -805.6, -800., -748.5, -769., -776., \
-774., -817.4, -812.8, -836.4, -833., -825., -837.2, -820., -791., \
-797., -766.6, -769.8, -782.6, -786.3}, {"G. diehli", 
1., -78., -106.4, -77., -124., -121., -72.4, -87.5, -94., -99., \
-134., -122.1, -149., -153., -141., -154., -137., -105., -111., -83., \
-87., -104., -105.}, {"G. diehli", 
2., -79.6, -105.8, -77., -124., -119., -72.1, -86., -100., -99., \
-134., -121.5, -148., -152., -142., -152., -135., -104., -110., \
-84.7, -86., -103., -107.}, {"P. abelii ", 
1., -214.09, -232.6, -209.24, -232.56, -227.49, -185.5, -204.5, \
-209.5, -213.9, -250.52, -249.8, -256.49, -249.85, -244.22, -257.96, \
-237.6, -219.2, -225.2, -198.8, -201.9, -223.3, -224.2}, {"P. abelii \
", 2., -214.93, -230.8, -209.97, -233.98, -230.51, -184.4, -204.4, \
-208.4, -214.1, -249.21, -250., -258.98, -250.1, -242., -256.86, \
-234.5, -225.9, -226.4, -201., -205.8, -225.1, -224.1}, {"P. \
pygmaeus", 
 1., -288.8, -280.5, -280.5, -265., -264., -238.5, -250.7, -234.2, \
-224.9, -258.9, -296.1, -259.5, -246.3, -234.5, -251.1, -212.5, \
-224.5, -219.6, -249.1, -230.4, -224.4, -233.}, {"P. pygmaeus", 
 2., -293.5, -284.3, -278.4, -256.8, -255.6, -236.3, -248.4, \
-233.4, -227.3, -261.4, -295.5, -262., -242.6, -233.8, -252.2, -212., \
-225.1, -220.3, -248.2, -230.9, -225.3, -233.7}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Significant manual cleaning was required for block of data in post.

The data:

```
data = {{{"ID", "Day", 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 
     12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 
     22.}, {"H. sapiens", 1., 145.7, 153.2, 164.6, 161.1, 170.8, 
     191.7, 179.2, 178.5, 198.5, 169.9, 135.8, 182.8, 205.3, 210.3, 
     197.3, 238.4, 207.4, 209., 188.6, 201.3, 210.2, 
     206.9}, {"H. sapiens", 2., 146.8, 152.7, 165.6, 165.1, 172.4, 
     189.2, 179.2, 193.9, 199.7, 172.9, 136.1, 181.8, 204.3, 212.3, 
     197.4, 238., 205.7, 211.5, 191.5, 204.3, 218.2, 
     204.2}, {"Pan troglodytes", 
     1., -200.9, -230.2, -205.5, -238.8, -237.3, -207.1, -213.2, \
-221.6, -225.9, -247.1, -242.6, -266.5, -259.1, -258., -266.1, -259., \
 -227.3, -228.9, -212.1, -213.6, -223.9, -225.1}, {"Pan troglodytes", 
     2., -199.4, -229.6, -203.5, -243.6, -238.6, -205.7, -213.1, \
-222.3, -227.3, -258.1, -242.9, -265.4, -265.1, -258., -269.9, -260., \
 -228.2, -233.3, -212.3, -215.1, -225.4, -223.6}, {"Pan verus", 1., 
     261.2, 273., 274., 283., 285.06, 300., 294., 305.037, 315.33, 
     289.08, 263.6, 298.46, 306.3, 316.7, 306.5, 331.6, 320.81, 323.7,
      298.13, 312.79, 319.2, 310.2}, {"Pan verus", 2., 264.1, 268.7, 
     273.1, 289.19, 288.03, 299.9, 291.9, 304.137, 316.54, 289.675, 
     263.4, 298.58, 309.3, 316.2, 306., 332.3, 323.31, 327.4, 297.26, 
     310.95, 321.8, 310.9}, {"Pan schweinfurthii ", 1., 230.6, 241.2, 
     241., 257.3, 253.3, 274.1, 265.9, 272.36, 280.147, 259.21, 229.8,
      268.19, 277.62, 286.6, 275.56, 306.3, 287.4, 292.04, 270.36, 
     283.35, 291.3, 281.13}, {"Pan schweinfurthii ", 2., 226.9, 237.9,
      239.9, 254.6, 257., 273.7, 262., 273.33, 282.84, 260.05, 229.6, 
     267.49, 278.23, 287.9, 272.72, 306.2, 287.58, 287.92, 270.85, 
     283.37, 292.3, 281.88}, {"Pan paniscus", 
     1., -421.9, -447., -420.9, -454.5, -451.7, -419.8, -427.8, \
-431.9, -445.7, -463.4, -459.2, -476.3, -470.1, -466.5, -475.5, \
-450.1, -439.5, -445.8, -417.4, -419.5, -434.4, -432.2}, {"Pan \
paniscus", 
     2., -426.2, -447.9, -421.5, -455.6, -453., -420.4, -428.7, \
-432.7, -441.5, -466.8, -459.5, -476.4, -470.9, -467.2, -474.7, \
-472.5, -437.5, -446.9, -416.4, -424.7, -433.1, -437.}, {"G. gorilla \
", 1., -175.9, -204., -175.1, -221., -217., -168., -187., -198., \
-213., -229., -220.8, -251.8, -251., -245., -256., -243., -211., \
-224., -190., -194., -210., -212.}, {"G. gorilla ", 2., -180.8, -205.,
      214.1, -228., -223., -167., -191., -195., -206., -242.9, \
-221.6, -251.8, -253., -243., -256., -243., -211., -224., -189.8, \
-196., -210., -215.}, {"G. graueri ", 1., 220., 192., 222., 177., 
     184., 228., 214., 205., 187., 162., 174., 147., 155., 162., 145.,
      170., 194., 186., 221.2, 215.5, 198.8, 198.3}, {"G. graueri ", 
     2., 221., 189., 226., 182., 179., 230., 214., 210., 188., 161., 
     172., 146., 153., 156., 146., 169., 193., 189., 221.2, 220.6, 
     202.2, 196.9}, {"G. beringei", 
     1., -763., -793.5, -762.2, -810.3, -802., -749.7, -771., -777.,  \
-783., -828., -809.3, -836.9, -833., -828., -837.9, -809., -788., \
-795., -767.3, -768.4, -789., -782.8}, {"G. beringei", 
     2., -763.3, -791.9, -761.3, -805.6, -800., -748.5, -769., -776., \
 -774., -817.4, -812.8, -836.4, -833., -825., -837.2, -820., -791.,  \
-797., -766.6, -769.8, -782.6, -786.3}, {"G. diehli", 
     1., -78., -106.4, -77., -124., -121., -72.4, -87.5, -94., -99.,  \
-134., -122.1, -149., -153., -141., -154., -137., -105., -111., -83., \
 -87., -104., -105.}, {"G. diehli", 
     2., -79.6, -105.8, -77., -124., -119., -72.1, -86., -100., -99., \
 -134., -121.5, -148., -152., -142., -152., -135., -104., -110.,  \
-84.7, -86., -103., -107.}, {"P. abelii ", 
     1., -214.09, -232.6, -209.24, -232.56, -227.49, -185.5, -204.5,  \
-209.5, -213.9, -250.52, -249.8, -256.49, -249.85, -244.22, -257.96,  \
-237.6, -219.2, -225.2, -198.8, -201.9, -223.3, -224.2}, {"P. abelii \
", 2., -214.93, -230.8, -209.97, -233.98, -230.51, -184.4, -204.4,  \
-208.4, -214.1, -249.21, -250., -258.98, -250.1, -242., -256.86,  \
-234.5, -225.9, -226.4, -201., -205.8, -225.1, -224.1}, {"P. \
pygmaeus", 
     1., -288.8, -280.5, -280.5, -265., -264., -238.5, -250.7, \
-234.2,  -224.9, -258.9, -296.1, -259.5, -246.3, -234.5, -251.1, \
-212.5, -224.5, -219.6, -249.1, -230.4, -224.4, -233.}, {"P. \
pygmaeus", 
     2., -293.5, -284.3, -278.4, -256.8, -255.6, -236.3, -248.4, \
-233.4, -227.3, -261.4, -295.5, -262., -242.6, -233.8, -252.2, -212., \
 -225.1, -220.3, -248.2, -230.9, -225.3, -233.7}}};
```

If I interpret correctly: there are 11 species with data from 2 days (11 replications). 
The OP suggests the data recorded are "variances" (there are 22 values per sepcies) and the OP states "from which I have taken the variance". However, variance should be non-negative.

The following plots "day 2" against "day 1" by species. This may not be desired output.

```
dat = Rest@data[[1]];
spec = dat[[All, 1]];
datm = #[[3 ;;]] & /@ (Thread[{#1, #2}] & @@@ GatherBy[dat, #[[1]] &]);
lpt = ListPlot[datm, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    PointLegend[Automatic, 
     Style[#, FontFamily -> "Arial"] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[spec], 
     LegendLayout -> (Grid[#, Frame -> True, Alignment -> Left] &)], 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Day 1", "Day 2"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 14}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

If the aim is to take means and variances of species. I leave other ways to visulaize, eg. error bar plots distribution plots up to the intention OP.

```
mnlp = ListPlot[List /@ (Mean /@ datm), 
   PlotLegends -> 
    PointLegend[Automatic, 
     Style[#, FontFamily -> "Arial"] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[spec], 
     LegendLayout -> (Grid[#, Frame -> True, Alignment -> Left] &)], 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Day 1", "Day 2"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 14}, ImageSize -> 600, 
   PlotLabel -> "Mean Values"];
varlp = ListPlot[List /@ (Variance /@ datm), 
  PlotLegends -> 
   PointLegend[Automatic, 
    Style[#, FontFamily -> "Arial"] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[spec], 
    LegendLayout -> (Grid[#, Frame -> True, Alignment -> Left] &)], 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Day 1", "Day 2"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 14}, ImageSize -> 600, 
  PlotLabel -> "Variance Values"];
```

Note: only minimal change was required-> the argument of `ListPlot`. The above objects are shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. That's exactly what I needed. Sorry I meant to say I'd taken the sum of xyz and the goal was the variance. Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 2):

```
reorgdata = GatherBy[data[[1]], #[[2]] &][[2 ;;, All, 3 ;;]];
variances = Thread[Variance /@ reorgdata];
means = Thread[Mean /@ reorgdata];
Row[{ListPlot[means, PlotLabel -> "means", ImageSize -> 300], 
    ListPlot[variances, PlotLabel -> "variances", ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]